# how to install venn diagram module on highcharts using npm?

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I installed highcharts using NPM, but it doesn't come with venn module. I want to use venn digram, so i need that module. Can someone help me with how to install venn module on highcharts?

i installed highcharts using : npm install highcharts --save

Comment: [Venn series](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/venn-series) and [Installation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation)

Answer (score 2):

All Highcharts modules are included in `highcharts` npm package. You need to import and initialize `venn` module in your project:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import vennInit from 'highcharts/modules/venn'

vennInit(Highcharts)
```

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#importing-highcharts-modules

Comment: I tried doing that, but for some reason, venn is not included in my modules when I install Highcharts. i get below error ::

This dependency was not found:

Comment: * highcharts/modules/venn in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}]]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/ChartContainerProfile.vue



To install it, you can run: npm install --save highcharts/modules/venn

Comment: When I run above command, it gives me error as well saying :: "Could not install from "highcharts/modules/venn" as it does not contain a package.json file."

Comment: Hi @user3321874, Could you check if there is the same problem with other modules (for example `exporting`)?

Comment: I do have exporting, drilldown and funnel modules, which I am using. they are all included in modules folder inside node_modules/highcharts, but I just don't have Venn module. Their documentation says it comes with all those modules, but unfortunately, i don't see venn in it.! thank you.!

Comment: Oh, I got it when I upgraded highcharts version.!! thank you so much for your time.!!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your highcharts version to 7.0.0 or higher, and that will include venn diagram module.